# Disable the published MVC3 solution to be published again

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-deployment, publishing

**Hi,**

My application is in Asp.Net MVC3 coded in C#.Net. I have published my solution and deployed it on IIS on the client machine. For this particular client we are not using any online server, we have published on client's local machine on IIS and from that machine only they will use it. The only problem we are having is regarding the security of the application as our client is accessible to the database as well as the application.

So under this scenario any technically aware person can take the published copy of the application and publish it again on their machine.

**My query**

How can i prevent the user from redeploying it on any other machine. Something like we have in the desktop application where the IP of the machine is taken and that particular application can `run only on that machine.`
I want my published content to be used only on the machine im have published and if the user wishes to copy the published content and deploy on other machine then it should not happen.

I have googled a lot regarding this but no result is returned in this regard.

```
Suggest how can i achieve the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can secure your ASP.NET MVC application to run on only 1 computer.  Here are some  companies that offer copy protection:

- DeployLX by Xheo (http://xheo.com/)
- Cryptolicensing by LogicNP Software (http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm)
- IntelliLock by Eziriz (http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm)
- ElecKey 2.0 R8 by Sciensoft (http://www.sciensoft.com/products/eleckey)